# Can I change an Adobe Air application icon in actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, icons, window

I'm trying to make an application in adobe air where you can externally load icons into the application. Can I change the window application icon in actionscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read this [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/stopwatch_dock_system_tray.html) or [this documenrtation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=taskbar_1.html)?

It look as is code like this will do it:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = 
            [bmp16x16.bitmapData, bmp128x128.bitmapData];
```

You'll have to get the bitmapData from the image you want to use, though.

Comment: :-(  So long ago; I have no idea what I originally linked to.  You might find help on the Apache Flex mailing list: http://flex.apache.org/ or on the Adobe Air Forum https://community.adobe.com/t5/air/bd-p/air?page=1&sort=latest_replies&filter=all or through Harmon who now maintains Adobe AIR https://airsdk.harman.com/ 
Good luck!

Comment: Also, The NativeApplication API mentioned changes the Application Icon in system tray/Dock. It will create an icon in system-tray if it does not exist. However the title bar icon or the icon in taskbar (in windows) did not change.